# Laravel 5 GET allowed but POST not allowed

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am working on a project in Laravel 5 and I am stuck in a very weird issue. I am trying to create a user profile section where the user can edit details and the form is submitted to a `POST` route `profile/update`.

For some reason I am getting a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` but I am sure I have declared it in the routes file like so:

```
Route::post('profile/update', 'ProfileController@update');
```

Just out of curiosity I changed it to `GET` in both my routes file and the code that is sending the ajax request. To my surprise it works fine. I cannot understand how. For obvious reasons I cannot send a `GET` request for update profile.

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/profile/update',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: $('form#profile-form').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        return request.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $("meta[name='token']").attr('content'));
    }
});
```

Controller method:

```
public function update(UpdateProfileRequest $request)
{
    $data =  $request->all();
    $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);

    $user = auth()->user()->update($data);

    return response()->json(auth()->user(), 200);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add your ajax code also.

Comment: Yeah I should have done that. Here it is.

Comment: When you change the route to `get`, have you change the ajax for `get` also?

Comment: Yes I have. I change it in both places. :)

Comment: There might be a routing conflict. Could we see your entire `routes.php` file?

Comment: If you fear that I might have `profile/{wildcard}` route above it, I don't. In fact, I placed this route on the top of the file to make sure but it still won't work. The project is kind of a private project. My employer doesn't wish me to show more code than necessary. I hope you wanted to see the routes file to make sure of the wild card. Or do you have something else in mind?

Comment: I just wanted to check for conflicts. Try commenting out every other route to ensure there are no overlaps.

Comment: I tried commenting. Doesn't work still.

Comment: When you run the ajax and check your browser console, does the request show up as a POST?

Comment: It does indeed. I have been banging my head at the console for some time now and still cannot figure what is going wrong. I guess banging doesn't work after all. :)

Comment: Can you show your update method from controller?

Comment: Here you go. This working fine with the `GET` just BTW. :)

Comment: If you skip the ajax and post the form as normal, do you get the same error (if so, that'd point to the JS being the problem...) Could be worth a shot.

Comment: Have you run `php artisan route:clear`, `php artisan optimize` and `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Now I did. Still not luck. It is still giving me back a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` but when I change it to get, it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after banging my head for a few hours another day, I realized that the old developer left a piece of code in the form somewhere:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

And there it is. Even though my ajax call was `POST`, Laravel thought it to be `PUT`. Anyway thank you everyone who commented and tried to help. Appreciate it.